"horizontal parenthesis" under text for metrical notation of verse
I am using a quite common notation for short and long syllables when working with poetry and its metrical form.
There is one example however, that I struggle to reproduce typographically. What I want is:

What I get so far in a MWE:
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{junicode}
\setmainfont{junicode}
\begin{document}
    \char"F706×
\end{document} 

How do I achieve that "horizontal parenthesis" under the text's baseline?

I think the established typographical term for the "horizontal parenthesis" is "bow".

The \bow macro of the metrix package may be what you're looking for.

The self-description of the metrix package is as follows: "The package may be used to type the prosodics/metrics of (latin) verse; it provides macros to typeset the symbols standing alone, and in combination with symbols, giving automatic alignment."
Aside: If you type \bow{azerty}, the bow symbol won't collide with the descender part of the letter "y".
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{junicode}
\usepackage{metrix} % for '\bow' macro
\begin{document}

\bow{\char"F706 ×} \quad \bow{\char"F706\hspace{3mm}×}

\end{document}


With the package graphicx

With \rotatebox{90}{(} --> hotizontal parenthesis
With \resizebox{\mylg}{2pt} --> to horizontally extend the parenthesis to the width of the text
With \raisebox{-.8ex} --> to lower the parenthesis
\hspace*{-\mylg} --> to move the parenthesis back by the length of the text

code
% !TeX program = lualatex
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/732248/horizontal-parenthesis-under-text-for-metrical-notation-of-verse
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{junicode}
\setmainfont{junicode}
%
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newlength{\mylg}
\NewDocumentCommand{\horizontalePar}{ m }{
    \settowidth{\mylg} {#1}
    #1\hspace*{-\mylg}\raisebox{-.8ex}{\resizebox{\mylg}{2pt}{\rotatebox{90}{(}}}
}

\begin{document}
\horizontalePar{\char"F706×} and \horizontalePar{azerty}
\end{document} 



This works. I did, however, choose the other answer as the metrix package offers additional options for my case.
